# Replace first 2 letters of all matching words

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I have a long string: "§aSomething, §bthat this §csomething else" and it's dynamic, I want to know how I can replace all of those "§a" or whatever the number is to nothing.

Comment: "§aSomething, §bthat this §csomething else".replace("§a","")

Comment: okay I guess that's the only way then.

Comment: @AnamulHasan This will only replace the first occurrence of `"§a"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to increase the number of letters you can also use

```
var string = "§aSomething, §bthat this §csomething else"
string = string.replace(/[§][a-z]{1}/g, '');
```

where {1} represents the number of letters after §

Output:

```
Something, that this something else
```

Comment: Thanks bro, this is actually really helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Use `regular expression`

`"§aSomething, §bthat this §csomething else".replace(/§./g,"")`

`.` = Any single character

`g` = Global (search on entire string)

Comment: this will only replace the first instace

Comment: Nope, if it's regex replace then it will check your entire string and replace it

Comment: Wow I did not know that. Good thing you corrected me

Comment: @ChristianEsperar But only with the global modifier

Comment: @Andreas exactly!